# Set dimensions of element to equal responsive image dimensions

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building out flippable images on my site. I want the "back" of these images to have the same dimensions as the front.
My problem is that I'm using the Bootstrap img-responsive class on my images so the "back" dimensions need to update dynamically to match the "front".

Here's what I hypothetically want to do (I realize the CSS is not possible as written, just illustrating my goal). I'm using ng-animate to animate transitions and reveal the initially hidden "back" and hide the front (that aspect I'm in good shape with).

html:

```
<img class="front img-responsive" src="path/to/img.jpg" alt="">

<div class="back">Info about image</div>
```

css:

```
.back {
    height: [current height of .front]
    width: [current width of .front]
}
```

Comment: you tried it with ng-style ?

Comment: Something like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/1mdwqt3o/)?

Comment: @Narek, thank you for mentioning that. I hadn't actually used that directive yet, but it looks useful!

Comment: @Syed, thank you that works perfectly. I have a custom.js file that I keep separate from my Angular controllers, factories, etc. for jquery formatting. I'll just throw this in there!

Comment: @MattDionis: Please mark my answer below as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `height` and `width` of image using jQuery and the apply it to your `div`

```
<img class="front img-responsive" id="img" src="path/to/img.jpg" alt="">
<div class="back" id="info">Info about image</div>


$(document).ready(function () {        
var img = document.getElementById('img');
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
$("#info").width(width).height(height);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1mdwqt3o/)**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is how you will use it, but v1.3+ added support, and have found it just now...

See plunkr = http://plnkr.co/edit/utsD4RimPB6RSKXnAlLi?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html ng-app>  
  <head>  
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">  
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.0/angular.js"></script>  
   <style>  
    .mydiv {  
     height: {{height}}px;  
     width: {{width}}px;  
     background-color: red;  
    }  
   </style>  
  </head>  
  <body style="width:100%;height:100%;">  
   <div class="mydiv" ng-init="height= 100; width=200"></div>  
   h: {{height}} w: {{width}}  
  </body>  
 </html>
```

duplicate: http://noypi-linux.blogspot.com/2014/09/angularjs-binding-inside-of-style-tag.html